# Egress Traffic from Google Cloud

Tags: azure, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have hosted my application on a VM in Google Cloud in VPC. This application pulls data from my on-premise applications and pushes to Google Cloud Storage and Azure Blob Storage.

Since I am pushing data into Azure Blob Storage, is this egress traffic? Or since the machine is in VPC, this would be just internet traffic?

Answer (score 2):

> Since I am pushing data into Azure Blob Storage, is this egress
>   traffic?

From Azure Blob Storage perspective, it is not egress traffic. It is ingress traffic and you will not pay anything for bandwidth.

However from Google's VM perspective, the data going to Azure Blob Storage is egress traffic and you should be charged for the data transfer.